# How to change tab name in browser when user goes off from my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am making a website and everything is nicely done but I don't know that many things with javascript.

I was searching for something that will help me with this and found some similar things but it doesn't work in my case.

This is the problem/idea:

- User is on my site and the page name is eg. Hello ( tag)
  Then the user clicks on the other tab in the browser but doesn't close my website.
  When that happens my page title changes to eg. You went ?
  When he clicks on my tab again title changes back to default one.

So if someone can help me with the code and explain it a little bit.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a valid question IMHO. "How do I change the Page (tab) title when user loses focus."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to make use of the onblur and onfocus events for the window object.

So something like this (this is native javascript, no jquery).

```
<script>

window.onblur = function () { document.title = 'you went?'; }

window.onfocus = function () { document.title = 'you came back'; }

</script>
```

Comment: TypeError: Property 'onblur' of object [object global] is not a function

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos works in Chrome and IE - what browser you using?

Comment: +1 Yes. you are right, i retried in chrome and no error second time.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).focus(function() {
   document.title = 'defult title';
});

$(window).blur(function() {
   document.title = 'you went?';
});
```

Comment: +1. this kinda works if using jquery, replace `//do something` with `document.title = 'you went?';`

Comment: @Sefik_m (I'll say this since you've said you're new to javascript) this is using jQuery so make sure to reference the jQuery library...

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
window.addEventListener('blur',function(){
alert("please Came Back");
 document.head.title = "your tilte"
  });

 window.addEventListener('focus',function(){
 alert("Hi");
 document.head.title = "your tilte"
  });
```

Comment: TypeError: Property 'onblur' of object #<HTMLDocument> is not a function

Comment: document must be `$(window)`

Comment: this still does not work in chrome. you change the dom element but not the actual window (Chrome) element. You will need to use `document.title` it seems.

Comment: I test it using fiddle its working in chrome..@Anthony Hatzopoulos

Answer (score 0):

[best](https://medium.com/@alperen.talaslioglu/changing-page-title-dynamically-when-user-changes-tab-5d372554377c) for me is use:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var pageTitle = document.title;
  var attentionMessage = 'Come Back!';

  document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(e) {
    var isPageActive = !document.hidden;

    if(!isPageActive){
      document.title = attentionMessage;
    }else {
      document.title = pageTitle;
    }
  });
};
```